# MySQL Query IF with multiple statements

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

what im trying to do is a simple IF Condition within a MySQL command text, for example:

```
SET @var1=(SELECT ID 
           FROM table_a 
           WHERE ID=@ID_Parameter 
           ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1); 

IF @var1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM table_b 
    WHERE ID=@var1; 

    UPDATE table_c 
    SET ID=@var1 
    WHERE ID=@ID_Parameter;
END IF;
```

Obviously this just doesnt work, it complains that i have a sintax error inside my query, can ive searched google and found no way to use IF inside this specific case, any help appreciated.

Best Regards,
Eugen

Comment: MySQL only allows the `IF` clause in code blocks -- stored procedures, functions, and trigger.

Comment: If you want solve it on `C#`, you probably need check a `Database with C# tutorial`. For MySQL write a store procedure.

Comment: So what you guys are saying is there is no way for me to do this in the commandtext? I do not want to create a stored procedure or function or trigger, its not the proper place where that code should go in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `IF` at all. In your delete statement, if `@var1` is null it evaluates to:

```
DELETE FROM table_b 
WHERE ID = NULL
```

Which won't delete any records (`null = null` isn't `true`).
You can always add:

`AND @var1 IS NOT NULL;`

Which is unnecessary in this case, in other cases it is needed, like in the update statement below. It does add clarification to the function of the code, so may be good to add anyway.

You can change your update query to:

```
UPDATE table_c 
SET ID=@var1 
WHERE ID=@ID_Parameter
   AND @var1 IS NOT NULL;
```

With this change you can remove the `if` and get the functionality you request.

Comment: it will delete some rows as there exist some rows with no ID reference which are processed by the program as templates rows rather than actual data rows. So that way is really a no go for me

I really need something like IF in my case

Comment: You can add `and @var1 is not null` to the `where` clause. It won't be necessary though. If a value is `null` `= null` still evaluates to false, the correct way to check for `null` is `IS NULL`. The equal operator `=` doesn't work that way with `null`

Comment: Please post your comment as solution so i can select it as answear, i was hoping there were IF in a command statement but there isnt and the condition of "and @var1 is not null" pasted into all sub commands is the only viable option.